# Angular 7: Transfer data from one application to another application

Tags: javascript, angular, cross-browser, cross-domain, dom-events

I have 2 Angular applications. I want to pass data from one application to another application which are running on different domain. I tried with window.postMessage but, I am not getting any data in 2nd Application.

1st Application has below code

```
const w = window.open('http://192.168.5.134:1210/', ''); 
w.postMessage('Hello Message!', 'http://localhost:4200');
```

2nd Application has below code

```
  window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);

  function receiveMessage(event) {
    alert(event.origin);
    if (event.origin !== "http://localhost:4200") {
      return;
    }
    alert(event.data.data);

  }
```

Comment: this may help you `https://medium.com/disney-streaming/combining-multiple-angular-applications-into-a-single-one-e87d530d6527`

Comment: @Edison - Thank you for the link. We can't do this.

Comment: @RishabhShah what about `socket` ? you can implement that

Comment: @YashRami - I am not sure about socket. Can you give me any idea on it, if you have any reference.

Comment: He's talking about an approach like socket.io, but doesn't change the fact that you will run a separate service and not a service integrated in angular.

Comment: @Robert - right!

Answer (score 1):

Due to security reasons, two different domains can not communicate with each other.

That goes for `postMessage`, `localStorage`, or anything related to your browser.

The only suitable option is to make them communicate to a third party, let it be a standalone client, an API, or anything else that isn't related to the browser itself.

You maybe could use an Iframe, but I'm not sure about it, and I wouldn't even know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2 application that are running on different domain, it means that the best method to communicate with each other is setting up an api that allow such communication. So you need a backend that handle the api.

Comment: We could have done that but, We are making service call and whatever response we are getting, we need to pass to another application in new tab which is running on different domain, and we can't do anything from backend.

Comment: There is no other concrete mode, as @Maryannah said because of Same-origin policy communication is not suitable with things related to browser, even using Iframe is crazy to do.